# Data in a variable disappears after while loop

Tags: javascript

I am getting data from my API like this:

```
function getWeight (username) {
/* This function takes a username as a parameter,
    then it calls the API URL using the username
    so that it gets the weights of that particular
    user.
*/
  var weights;

  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/weight/api/get_weight_data_admin/'+username,
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function (data) {
        weights = data
      }
    });

  getWeightPlots(weights);
}
```

The above code is working as expected when I do console.log(weights) it shows me exactly what I expect:
[image: console.log(weights)]

The problem lies in the code below; the list which I create in the function below, and append values to it inside the while loop, after exiting while loop I see no values in it.

```
function getWeightPlots (weights) {
/**
 * This function takes a list of dictionaries, which contain
 * dates when the weight was entered and the weight itself.
 * It returns a list of weights that can be used for plotting on
 * the graph.
 */

  var weightList = [];

  // get the last 12 months
  var months = getMonths();

  var numWeights = weights.length;

  var i = 0;
  var y = 0;
  while (y < months.length) {
    var weightMonthNum = weights[i]
    weightMonthNum = weightMonthNum['date']
    weightMonthNum = weightMonthNum.split('-');
    weightMonthNum = parseInt(weightMonthNum[1])

    var monthNum = monthToMonthNum(months[y])

    if (weightMonthNum < monthNum){
      i++;
    }
    else if (weightMonthNum == monthNum) {
      weightList.push(1);
      i++;
      y++;
    }
    else {
      y++;
      weightList.push(0);
    }
  }

  console.log(weightList);
}
```

I tried debugging and everything seems to be working fine, any ideas?

Comment: Can you access the 'weights' array inside the 'getWeightPlots' function? Try doing a *console.log(weights)* inside the getWeightPlots function.

Comment: can  let me know what this `getMonths()` function will return ?

Comment: @AnimeshKumar Yes I can access weights array, and it's working perfectly.

Comment: @NarendraJadhav It returns past 12 months.

Answer (score 0):

When `getWeightPlots` is invoked `weights` is empty (undefined). Wait for ajax to finish then call it in the `success` method.

Comment: They are using the (deprecated) `async: false` mode.